# IE6 being a pain. When I resize the browser my UL moves

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I did some checking over my site today to see whether it was Cross Browser Friendly.

Turns out that it is... Except IE6...

So, my question to you lot is:
**Why, in IE6, is my `<UL>` moving when I resize the browser window?**

Unfortunately I cannot provide any code as I'm not at my desk, but I'm sure I am not the only person who has come across this bug!

The basic problem is that I have an element (UL) with:
`position: relative;`
 `bottom: 160px;`
 `left: 370px;`
 `top: -1px;`
 `*top: 4px;`

And when I resize the IE6 window (not scroll, or drag - just resize) - the element moves about 100px right.

Anyone encountered anything like this before - tis a first for me!

Thank you!

Comment: I've seen that kind of thing before, but not with the CSS you provide. You may need to provide a bit more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be the answer, but if your page has any jQuery that alters the layout of the page, this could be where the problem lies.  If you run your page in an application like IETester, try a different version (especially IE 5.5) as this should block the jQuery and stop the script running.

Comment: Well bugger me sideways - the problem was that the jQuery was adjusting the layout ever-so-slightly and pushing out the entire `<ul>` - lucky bloody guess @ardman!